# Safely share unique_ptr across threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, smart-pointers

How do you safely share `unique_ptr` across threads? I need one thread to be able to reset the underlying object, and the other thread to be able to access it in a safe way.
There is no `atomic_exchange` for `unique_ptr`

This works but seems wrong: if I reference a unique_ptr, it's no longer unique...

```
void test1() {
    /*
    Works
    */
    std::unique_ptr<int> upt = std::make_unique<int>(100);
    std::mutex m;

    std::thread t1([&]() {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        upt.reset();
        upt = std::make_unique<int>(123);
    });
    std::thread t2([&]() {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        printf("%i\n", *upt);
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

If I move the unique_ptr, it does not work:

```
void test2() {
    /*
    Segmentation fault
    */
    std::unique_ptr<int> upt = std::make_unique<int>(100);
    std::mutex m;

    std::thread t1([upt = std::move(upt), &m]() mutable {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        upt.reset();
        upt = std::make_unique<int>(123);
    });
    std::thread t2([upt = std::move(upt), &m]() mutable {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        printf("%i\n", *upt);
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

---

Edit:
Here is a more complete example of what I'm trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class A {
public:
  A(int i){a=i;}
  ~A(){/*properly detroy A*/}
  void foo(){std::cout<<"A::foo() a="<< a << std::endl;}
  void bar(){std::cout<<"A::bar() a="<< a << std::endl;}
private:
  int a;
};

class B {
public:
  B(std::unique_ptr<A> a):a_ptr(std::move(a)){}
  ~B(){}
  void foo(){
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_a);
    a_ptr->foo();
  }
  void bar(){
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_a);
    a_ptr.reset();
    a_ptr = std::make_unique<A>(123);
    a_ptr->bar();
  }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<A> a_ptr; /*unique_ptr or shared_ptr*/
  std::mutex m_a;
};

int main(){
  std::unique_ptr<A> a_ptr = std::make_unique<A>(100);
  std::unique_ptr<B> b_ptr = std::make_unique<B>(std::move(a_ptr));
  std::thread t1 ([&](){b_ptr->foo();});
  std::thread t2 ([&](){b_ptr->bar();});
  std::thread t3 ([&](){b_ptr->foo();});
  
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();

  return 0;
}
```

The only difference is, methods of B are actually called by a grpc Service, something like:

```
class MyServiceImpl final : public MyService::Service {
public:
  MyServiceImpl(std::unique_ptr<B> b):b_ptr(std::move(b)){}

  Status Foo(ServerContext* context, const FooRequest* request,
                  FooReply* reply) override {
    b_ptr->foo();
    return Status::OK;
  }

  Status Bar(ServerContext* context, const BarRequest* request,
                  BarReply* reply) override {
    b_ptr->bar();
    return Status::OK;
  }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<B> b_ptr;
};
```

grpc [states](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/) that

> all service methods can (and will!) be called from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: What is wrong with the working solution?

Comment: "share" and "unique_ptr" don't go together. It's a mutually-exclusive thing.

Comment: Unique means unique ownership, not unique usage. So the first example is correct but of course there might be better tools to share an `int`.

Comment: Do you understand why the non-working code does not work?

Comment: I usually advise to be careful with using std::shared_ptr, but this is one of those cases where std::shared_ptr is really the better option. Just capture by value and the lifetime of your values will be extended automatically to the lifetime of the threads that need access. Also note you can move a unique_ptr only once!

Comment: *"This works but seems wrong: if I reference a unique_ptr, it's no longer unique..."* You are sharing ownership of the pointer, or not of the pointed object (at least not directly). The unique pointer still has unique ownership of the pointed object. This is analogous to `std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T>>` which is weird but not necessarily wrong.

Comment: Do you really need to share `std::unique_ptr` and not its content (so here just the `int`)?

Comment: @PepijnKramer if I reset a `shared_ptr`, the other one still points at the initial value

Comment: `int` is a placeholder. I need the destructor to be called when I reset the pointer

Comment: @Jarod42 I need to make sure that at each time there is only one instance of the underlying object (in this case `int`). Both threads need to use the same instance, not a copy of it

Comment: The same way you capture `std::unique_ptr` by reference, you might capture the `int` by reference [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aq54535n5).

Comment: Taking inspiration from the other answer, if there was an `atomic_store` for `unique_ptr` which reset and reassigned the unique_ptr atomically, I think it would work

Comment: @Jarod42 it works, but the question is about smart pointers…

Comment: An atomic store would basically be useless. `printf("%i\n", *upt);` is no-atomic regarding the retrieval of the address of the int and the evaluation of the value, i.e. there's no guarantee the reference returned by `*upt` does not become dangling just before the `int` is evaluated for passing to `printf`. In real code a more complex object would likely be passed around by reference increasing the likelyhood of this becoming a dangling reference.

Comment: You'll probably end up using a [`std::shared_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex), if you're accessing the object from multiple threads... Depending on the likelyhood of the lock object being locked for reading you may need to implement logic for the producer thread to eventually be able acquire the write lock or you may end up with the producer thread being lifelocked...

Comment: Correct, but so does moving a unique_ptr. Looks like you don't need a pointer at all. Just have a class with a member and some threadsafe getters/setter. Then create an instance of that class before both threads in main and pass references to it in main. That class internally may or may not have a unique pointer to manage reallocateable data but that is then an implementation detail. All in all I think you're better of explaining WHAT you want to do instead of HOW you are now doing it.

Comment: Capturing a reference to the `unique_ptr` accomplishes the ability to reset. But you will need a mutex preventing one thread from writing to the `unique_ptr` (and deleting the old object) while another thread reads from the `unique_ptr` or, having read the pointer, accesses the old object. Even if there were an atomic_reassign for unique_ptr, that would not cure the race condition, because it wouldn't protect all the code using the target of the pointer.  So the first code snippet with every thread acting on the same `unique_ptr`, synchronizing through a mutex, is as good as it gets.

Comment: Note that the race condition between resetting the pointer (deleting the old object) and other threads accessing the old object is the reason that Linux has the RCU pattern and not atomic exchange.

Comment: Shared data concurrency with threads and mutexes is usually considered a bad idea as it lacks e.g. composability - you can easily introduce errors by combining two perfectly working programs, and it often does not provide the performance benefit you hope for when load increases and you start to suffer contention.

Comment: @BenVoigt is RCU my solution ?how would the example look like, if rewritten using RCU?

Comment: @Jens i see, but in this case I have no choice, as concurrency is implicit in grpc and in my case there cannot be more instances of class A.